# Win32 Low Level Assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, inline-assembly

do you know where I can find Windows Low Level Assembly examples programs?

I have some exemples using macros (NASM, MASM) but I want pure assembly, in order I can build a shellcode later.

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: No, I want to draw a windows form (using CreateWindow). Thanks!

Comment: By pure assembly I mean "mov eax, ebx" intructions... I mean no use of macros, like "invoke CreateWindows". Understand?

Comment: Checkout `www.masm32.com` site. The forum may help you.

Comment: @Preet Sangha: before .NET, assembly meant something quite different - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language :)

Comment: @snemarch - of course you are absolutely right - I stopped using the word by itself probably when I stopped programming in it. I use assembly languae or assembler for it now. For some reason I just didn't make the connection. I must have been half asleep when I wrote it - thanks for the wake up!

Comment: @Preet Sangha: That thing under your desk. The humming thing. It doesn't speak C#.

Comment: @matt : Lol - I refer the gentleman to the comment I gave 2 weeks ago!

Comment: @Preet Sangha: How do I find this comment?

Comment: @matt - I was refering to the comment I made above where I mentioned I was asleep. No worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial might be usefull for you: [winamtut](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigwin/old/workshops/winasmtut.pdf)

Also this [topic](http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=10325.0) in MASM forum is great too.

If your architeture is x64 so try this [link](http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=11310.0) too.

And finally if you're interested in some theory, maybe this [link](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/Page_win32/WindowsAsmPgm/html/Ch06.html#1005082) could be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Doing Windows GUI stuff in assembly language is a *lot* of work. This is why the examples you've found use macros - it takes away some of the pain.

If you really want pure assembly language, a great way is to ask your compiler. Write some C code to call `CreateWindow` or whatever, and then generate an assembly listing from the compiler (or step through it with a debugger).

Comment: I've tried to do so... but the compiler does some crazy stuffs... it's difficult to follow... there too many Windows API calls. I'm trying to do so using ollydbg, but even so I'm not been able to do it...

Comment: It's best first to see other's code. But instead of ollydbg or any debugger, a static code analysis with IDA is much better. (There is free version available).

Answer (score 1):

If by "pure assembly" you mean "not done as a macro or library" then this is what you have to do:

- download the [masm32 package](http://masm32.com/masmdl.htm)
- check through the copius amount of samples, there will be many using `CreateWindow` or `CreateWindowEx`
- start your own program
- link in `windows.h`
- use the `invoke` macro to call `CreateWindow` or `CreateWindowEx`
- if you don't want to use `invoke` then just `push` the parameters onto the stack and `call` the functions directly - as this is what invoke does for you anyway

You can also get lots of help using the MASM package from the [masm forum](http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?).

Comment: The poster wants "pure assembly", yet you suggest the most macro-heavy assembly package out there? :P - btw, you should fix "MASM package" to "MASM32 package", there's a big difference between the two.

Comment: @snemarch, the macros are there, but you don't have to use them. For instance, i told the OP how to avoid the *invoke* macro. FYI, the MASM32 package is Steve Hutchesson's packaging up of the MASM compiler with a bunch of other tools, libraries and tutorials. I am well aware of the differences - i used to be a mod on that forum. So stop nit-picking.

Comment: Calling it "the MASM package" is incorrect, though, and makes it sound like it's a Microsoft-supplied/supported package... which it isn't.

Comment: @snemarch, we are still splitting hairs with this, but let's be even more exact: redistribution rights for the MASM assembler were granted to Steve by MS. So it isn't **supported** by MS, but redistribution rights were **gifted** by MS. Steve also makes it totally clear in the doco that MS do not actively support the versions he distributes, and that they have absolutely no commitment for the package as a whole - hence my comment that the people on the forum offer the help/support. I think we've beaten this dead horse enough now...

Comment: All I'm objecting to is not calling things by their right name; I always found it misrepresentative to choose the name "MASM32" for the package anyway, but let's leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to really (and quickly) learn win32 assembly is to decompile simple win32 programs. You could download lena's reversing tutorials from tutsforyou.com. Alternative you could tryout the reverse me's from osix.net - they have some pretty straight forward programs for you to reverse, and the best part is you get to see the masm32 sourcecode after completing the level.

tools: ollydbg, masm32 etc.

books: win32 assembler coding by Goppit, the arteam's PE compendium, intel developers handbook

hxxp://osix.net

hxxp://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.17

hxxp://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very pleased with your "*in order I can build a shellcode later.*" - it's stuff like that which gives assembly a bad name.

I'd suggesty you take a look at [FASM](http://flatassembler.net/) instead of MASM, though, since it's "closer to the metal", and directly supports binary output.

Comment: this is just one use of Assembly programming. And learn how to build a shellcode is really cool

Comment: -1 since knowing how to build shellcode is an essential part of any malware analyst / exploit writer's toolset. It's not only criminals that need to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For learning to build shellcode I would suggest creating a very simple c program that does what you want the shellcode to do and than disassemble that using IDA or Immunity (or whatever debugger / dissasembler that you are familiar with). Than you can see what the instructions are that are being used.

I would also recommend the following books:

[Hacking: The Art of Exploitation (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271441)

[The Shellcoder's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047008023X)